# Get value of input elements in a hidden form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

It seems that jQuery can't access the value of hidden inputs (form elements in general) located in a hidden element; say Form or a div. I think it's the browser which responsible for this behavior, right ?

I have a 2 tabs view, the first tab includes an image editing panel, the other tab includes the image information; which is a form, most of the time the user will be on the first tab, and what i am trying to do is to automatically submit the form and save the image every 10 seconds or so.

All of the above is done, but the problem is that when i open the first tab and the other one becomes hidden the values of the form elements becomes no longer accessible, when i switch to the form tab and click "save" everything works fine !

So, is there a way to get input values form a hidden form ?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any problems accessing properties of hidden elements ([fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/joshleitzel/PpHVK/)) -- are you sure the form isn't being *removed* from the DOM?

Comment: Also, jQuery is browser independent.

Comment: Yes i am sure, it's a simple Tabs set.

Comment: @Dewan159 whether the contents of tab 2 is loaded dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**:hidden**](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector.

```
$( "input:hidden" ).val();
```

Comment: I think :hidden is for input[type=hidden] elements, and in my case the elements aren't hidden; they are in a temporarly hidden form

Comment: @Dewan159 so what is the issue...as Josh comment jQuery does not have issue with hidden elements..you can access it if form is hidden....

Comment: I know, but the problem is that it doesn't work, and i must open the tab that holds the form to submit the form ! :(

Comment: Look, we have 2 tabs one with an image and another with a form. When the form tab is active i can access it's inputs' values easly by code, but when the other tab is active i can't.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this

I have made a Demo with a hidden form and i am able to get value Normally

```
$("#btnGetForm").click(function(){
alert($("#hiddenForm").find(':input').val());
alert($('input[type=radio]:checked', '#hiddenForm').val());
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/ZxcZx/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdvalue" id="hdvalue" value="1">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var hiddenvalbox=$("#hdvalue").val();
});
</script>
```